# Jquery loops through php array, taps API and pushes back results to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, api

I have a php array - say startups[] - containing 36000 startup names. I want to use those names to construct a URL API endpoint.

I have failed to figure out how to use Jquery to loop through this php array, and for each of those 36000 entries make an api call to retrieve the id attached to the name of the startup.

I am also wondering how I could update the id  column in mysql corresponding to the name of the startup.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: wut. you realize php is server side and jquery is client side right?

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < startups.length; i++) { $.ajax('yourscript.php?id=' + startups[i], ...); }`. Hideiously inefficient, though. You'd be going 36,000 http requests. Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a page where you need to echo out an php array, probably the easiest way is to just json encode the array and print it where you need it like:

Using PHP 5.4+ short open/echo

```
  <?=json_encode($startup)?>
```

As noted in the comments to your question, this will trigger a large number of http requests and may not be the best approach.

Comment: I do understand this sounds really inefficient, but I'm essentially trying to scrap a database through the API to do some statistical analysis...